# how to sort lists within list in user defined order?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I want to sort lists of mathematical operators (stored as strings) in order of precedence (*,/,+,-) within a list. There are thousands of lists within my list.

E.g.

```
my_lists = [['*','+','-'],['-','*','*'],['+','/','-']]
```

should become:

```
new_list = [['*','+','-'],['*','*','-'],['/','+','-']]
```

Is there a way to sort the lists within my list in a user defined order?

Comment: Implement a comparator that you can later pass to the sorted method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the priority with a dictionary, like this

```
>>> priority = {'*': 0, '/': 1, '+': 2, '-': 3}
```

and then sort the individual lists, with the value from the `priority`, like this

```
>>> [sorted(item, key=priority.get) for item in my_lists]
[['*', '+', '-'], ['*', '*', '-'], ['/', '+', '-']]
```

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to create a new list of operators and store the operators in the desired precedence you want(you may change the precedence anytime), and then use the index of operators as a `key` to do the sorting.

You may simply do it by passing a `key` to the sorted function as:

```
my_lists = [['*','+','-'],['-','*','*'],['+','/','-']]
operators = ['*', '/', '+', '-']

new_list = [sorted(i, key = operators.index) for i in my_lists]
>>> [['*', '+', '-'], ['*', '*', '-'], ['/', '+', '-']]
```

however you mentioned a tuple in the question as `(*,/,+,-)`, so I tried to solve the issue using list, but using a dictionary would be a cleaner way as @thefourtheye suggested.

Comment: You do not need to use lambda function: `key=operators.index` will work. ;)

Comment: The lists are small here. So it wouldn't be a big deal, but if the `operators` is a little lengthier, `operators.index` would eat up a lot of time.

Comment: As far as **operators** is concerned, I don't guess there would be hundreds of them :P, but anyways yours method is better, I admit.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the optional `key` argument of the `.sort()` method.

If you want to do this in-place:

```
for sublist in my_lists:
    sublist.sort(key="*/+-".index)
```

Or if you want to create a new list:

```
new_list = [sorted(sublist, key="*/+-".index) for sublist in my_lists]
```

Note that using dictionnary may be more efficient if you have many lists:

```
d = {"*": 0, "/": 1, "+": 2, "-": 3}
key = d.get
```